# How are accumulating snapshots implemented in hive

Tags: hive, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

Accumulating snapshots have rows that need to be updated for every process change. How is this implemented in hive, when we cannot update the record?

So far I can only think of implementing this as a SCD2 table.